# Autoupdate the desktop background from an online photo webcam

Tags: desktop, webcam

I would like to set my desktop background to a webcam picture that updates several times an hour, for instance to this [view of Tegernsee](http://www.foto-webcam.org/webcam/wallberg/current/full.jpg). I am looking for a way to automatically get that picture every couple of minutes from the internet and update the desktop background. How can I do that (I would prefer a bash or applescript solution)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to make this work with launchd. This requires two steps: First creating a script that downloads the webcam picture, and second creating a LaunchAgent plist file that will call the script every so often.

This method will update the background picture of a specific Space, but only while you are on that space (also, when logging in and maybe when waking from sleep).

## First step: Creating a script that downloads the picture and changes the desktop background

1. Create a folder, e.g. `~/Library/Desktop Pictures/Webcam`.
2. Select that folder to be your desktop backgrounds folder in System Preferences → Destkop & Screen Saver.
3. Write a text file with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   shopt -s extglob # required for fancy rm
   # This script updates the desktop background of a specific Space to a webcam picture
   # while you are currently on that space.
   #
   # Choose a webcam:

   remotepic=http://www.foto-webcam.org/webcam/wallberg/current/full.jpg

   # Choose a desktop backgrounds pictures folder of the Space where you want to see the webcam
   # (you have to set this manually in System Preferences → Destkop & Screen Saver):

   webcampicturefolder=~/Library/Desktop\ Pictures/Webcam

   # check the desktop background pictures folder of the current Space
   currentpicturefolder=`osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to get pictures folder of current desktop"`
   # only proceed if you are currently on the space where you want to see the webcam
   if [ "$currentpicturefolder" == "$webcampicturefolder" ] ; then
     localpic="$webcampicturefolder"/$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S).jpg
     backup="$webcampicturefolder"/backup.jpg
     #remove all but the previous backup file and txt files:
     rm "$webcampicturefolder"/!(*txt|`basename "$backup"`) 2>>/dev/null
     # get the new picture unless there is a connection failure (-f flag):
     curl -fs -o "$localpic" "$remotepic"
     # make a backup of the new picture:
     cp "$localpic" "$backup" 2>>/dev/null
     # if no new picture has been downloaded, copy from backup:
     cp "$backup" "$localpic"
     # see http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html
     osascript -e "
     tell application \"System Events\"
       tell current desktop
         set picture rotation to 0
         set picture to POSIX file \"$localpic\"
       end tell
     end tell
     "
   fi
   ```
4. Save the file, e.g. as `~/Library/Desktop Pictures/Webcam/getwebcam.sh`
5. Make it executable by issuing the following command in the Terminal:

   ```
   chmod u+x ~/Library/Desktop Pictures/Webcam/getwebcam.sh
   ```

## Second step: Creating a LaunchAgent plist that calls the script

1. Write a text file with the following content. You need to adapt the string `/Users/myusername/Library/Desktop Pictures/Webcam/getwebcam.sh` so it points to the script created in the first step. You cannot use a relative path with `~`. Change the dict elements with the "Minute" key as you see fit – you can add more of them. The integer determines at which minute of every hour the script will be called (see also `man launchd.plist` on your Terminal).

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
   <plist version="1.0">
   <dict>
     <key>Label</key>
     <string>me.myname.update-desktop-from-webcam</string>
     <key>ProgramArguments</key>
     <array>
       <string>/Users/myusername/Library/Desktop Pictures/Webcam/getwebcam.sh</string>
     </array>
     <key>RunAtLoad</key>
     <true/>
     <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
     <array>
       <dict>
         <key>Minute</key>
         <integer>01</integer>
       </dict>
       <dict>
         <key>Minute</key>
         <integer>16</integer>
       </dict>
       <dict>
         <key>Minute</key>
         <integer>31</integer>
       </dict>
       <dict>
         <key>Minute</key>
         <integer>46</integer>
       </dict>
     </array>
   </dict>
   </plist>
   ```
2. Save the text file to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/me.myname.update-desktop-from-webcam.plist` – the name should match the "Label" key in the file.
3. Load it by issuing the following command:

   ```
   launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/me.myname.update-desktop-from-webcam.plist
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [VideoWall HD](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/videowall-hd/id456846185?mt=12), available for US$1.99 in the App Store.

I don't use it myself, but I have a friend in Portland who likes it. She doesn't use a web-cam, but this capability is touted in the App Store splash info.

Comment: Many thanks for the tip. I trust it would work, though I have not tried it since I do not like the app store.